# How to make a randomly populated list recursively in SML/NJ

Tags: sml, smlnj

```
fun randomList(n) =  let 
    val theList = []
    val min = 1
    val max = 75
    val nextInt = Random.randRange(min,max)
    val r = Random.rand(1,1)
    val randomValue = nextInt r
    in  
    if n = 0 then [] 
    else 
    (randomValue::theList;
    randomList(n-1)) end;

randomList(50);
```

> I'm trying to populate a list with random numbers. I'm getting the
>   error `Warning: type vars not generalized because of value restriction
>   are instantiated to dummy types (X1, X2,...)` I've seen some different
>   possible reasons for this but I can't figure it out. What do I need to
>   change? I'm still not sure that the function even works because I
>   haven't been able to fully run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function which you give is giving the type:

```
val randomList = fn : int -> 'a list
```

So ask, why then is 'a not generalizing to int?
Lets look at the expression in the **else** branch.

```
- val foo = ({}; 5);
val foo = 5 : int
```

The expression (e1; e2) evaluates e1, and then evaluates and returns e2,
Throwing away the result of e1. From there, it should start to make sense why it is returning an *'a list*.

1. Move *theList* to a parameter.
2. Add a helper function passing the empty list, to it.
3. Returning *theList* after it has accumulated all the random numbers.
4. As you noted in the comments it helps to pull the random seed *r*
   to an argument of the helper function, so the random number generator doesn't generate keep generating the same number.

   we still use the same initial seed for every call of randomList so each call of the same length will return the same list.
   a better seed function can be found here:
   [Seeding Sml/NJ RNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351292/seeding-sml-njs-rng-on-a-windows-machine/42353271#42353271)

> ```
> fun randomList (n) =
>  let fun helper (n, s) theList =
>   if n = 0
>      then theList
>      else
>       let val min = 1
>           val max = 75
>           val nextInt = Random.randRange(min,max)
>           val randomValue = nextInt s
>        in helper (n - 1, s) (randomValue::theList)
>       end;
>  in helper (n, Random.rand(1, 1)) [] end;
> ```

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Coming from Java, SML is quite different. Thank you for the help. The only problem I have now is that the `randomValue` stays the same for the whole list. How do I get that value to reset after every run? The way I make a random number is a little confusing. I don't know what `val r` accomplishes. In java, I would just need `nextInt` and then `randomValue` would get a random value, but in SML it seems you have to use 3 variables to get a random value.

Comment: @XXIV updated the code, 'r', encapsulates the state of the seed, (And is actually the problem) updated my answer a bit.

Comment: Ah, okay. I was thinking it was the seed but still didn't know how to handle it. Thank you for the link and also for all the help!